# Find Key By Value In Array Inside Array Using Php

Tags: php

Hey Dear I am Making Referal System With 11 Level Of Referal So Ho Can I Show All Referals And There Level I Have Tried

```
Array
(
    [L1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL422632
            [1] => TL626461
        )

    [L2] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL4321
            [1] => TL191123
        )

    [L3] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL555938
        )

    [L4] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL197752
        )

    [L5] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL835309
        )

    [L6] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL495903
        )

    [L7] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL207447
        )

    [L8] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL427427
        )

    [L9] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL288884
        )

    [L10] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL251399
        )

    [L11] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL284394
        )

)
```

But I Don't Know Ho To Get L Number By Value For Example I Have TL284394 And I Want To Know Level So It Will Show L11 How Can I Do It

Comment: Please write your question properly. You're just making the readability worse when you capitalize the first letter of every word.

Comment: Why don't you do that by two foreach loops?

Comment: Because there’s zero code, and no mention of a database, I’ve removed the MySQL tag. Please post what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two foreach loop inside each other and array_search() like this:

```
$a = array("L1" => [ 0 => "TL422632" ],"L2"=> [ 0 => "TL422635" ]);

$x = "TL422635";

foreach($a as $key=>$value){

    if($x === $value){
        
        return $key;
    }else{

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
           if($x === $v){
            
               return array_search([$k=>$v],$a);
           }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: I’m unclear what the `array_search` does, the `$x === $v` does that already. Also, the OP’s sample data always uses sub-arrays, never single strings. As such, I think it could be simplified to this: https://3v4l.org/CKvIA